# JSP output stream from DB to excel is very slow for large record volumes

Tags: jsp, fileoutputstream, poi-hssf

I am calling a JSP program to extract data from a database to excel. The database table has 112 columns and 35k records. Its taking an hour to extract the data. Any suggestions on how to make it under 5 mins? I have seen many similar posts but could not find any that could improve the performance. Appreciate your suggestions. My working code below -

```html
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileOutputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSetMetaData"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Export Data to Excel File</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<%
  
        HSSFWorkbook writeWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet desSheet = writeWorkbook.createSheet("sheet");
  Connection connection = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  int counter=1;
  try{
   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@PRD:PRD","ABC","ABC");
   Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
   String sql = ("select * from tblnm");
   rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
   ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

            Row desRow1 = desSheet.createRow((short)0);
            for(int col=0 ;col < columnsNumber;col++) {
                Cell newpath = desRow1.createCell(col);
                newpath.setCellValue(rsmd.getColumnLabel(col+1));
            }
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Row number" + rs.getRow() );
                Row desRow = desSheet.createRow(rs.getRow());
                for(int col=0 ;col < columnsNumber;col++) {
                    Cell newpath = desRow.createCell(col);
                    newpath.setCellValue(rs.getString(col+1));  
                }
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/test.xls");
                writeWorkbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.flush();
                fileOut.close();
    out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");
                writeWorkbook.write(response.getOutputStream()); 
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to get data from database");
        }
 %>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code to pull the data dynamically instead of file out and byte array method.